# Flexslider not working as expected

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have been having this strange problem with FlexSlider where I basically copy the code for a thumbnail slider from flexslider's [demo page](http://flexslider.woothemes.com/thumbnail-slider.html) and I do a small modification for my needs but the carousel **never** synchronizes with the slider so it's useless. I've tried even the most basic example still not working as expected and no errors returned.

I'll explain it below but you can check the "working" example [here](https://www.casasenmeridabaspul.com/house-a/)

I include the css in my `<head>` section and the js in before the `</body>` tag closure. I though the minified version might've been causing the problem so for this example I am including the full scripts.

```
in head
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/flexslider/flexslider.css">

before body tag close
<script src="js/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

Then I have my slider and carousel the following way:

```
<div class="flexslider slider_casas">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img etc etc etc></li>
        <li><img etc etc etc></li>
        ........
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="flexslider carousel_casas">
    <ul class="slides">
        <li><img etc etc etc></li>
        <li><img etc etc etc></li>
        ........
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the end, for the initialization (after I've included flexslider.js), I use the following:

```
<script>

    $(window).load(function() {

        $('.carousel_casas').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: true,
            itemWidth: 140,
            itemMargin: 10,
            asNavFor: ".slider_casas"
        });

        $('.slider_casas').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            controlNav: false,
            animationLoop: true,
            sync: ".carousel_casas",
            slideshowSpeed: 4000,
            animationSpeed: 600,
            slideshow: false
        });
    });     

</script>
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: For more details, I am using it with Foundation 5, but I don't think that should affect.